# Hints and/or help needed for axiomatic deduction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Proof: $\forall x \forall y ((Ax \rightarrow Rxy) \rightarrow \neg Ay) \vdash \forall x (Rxx \rightarrow \neg Ax)$

Axioma schema's that can be used:

1 $(\forall x(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)) \rightarrow (\forall x \varphi \rightarrow \forall x \psi)$

2 $\varphi \rightarrow \forall x \varphi$ ($x$ not free in $\varphi$)

3 $\forall x \varphi  \rightarrow [t/x]\varphi$ (only if the term $t$ is free for $x$ in $\varphi$)

a $\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \varphi)$

b $\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \chi) \rightarrow ((\varphi \rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \chi))$

c $(\neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg \psi) \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \varphi)$

And Modus Ponens for deductions.

What I got so far:

$\Sigma = \{\forall x \forall y ((Ax \rightarrow Rxy) \rightarrow \neg Ay)\}$

1 $\Sigma \vdash \forall x \forall y ((Ax \rightarrow Rxy) \rightarrow \neg Ay)$ **assumption** 
2 $\vdash \forall x \forall y ((Ax \rightarrow Rxy) \rightarrow \neg Ay) \rightarrow \forall y ((Az \rightarrow Rzy) \rightarrow \neg Ay)$ **Axiom schema 3**
3 $\Sigma \vdash \forall y ((Az \rightarrow Rzy) \rightarrow \neg Ay)$ **MP, 1, 2**
4 $\vdash \forall y ((Az \rightarrow Rzy) \rightarrow \neg Ay) \rightarrow (Az \rightarrow Rzz) \rightarrow \neg Az$ **Axiom schema 3**
5 $\Sigma \vdash (Az \rightarrow Rzz) \rightarrow \neg Az$ **MP, 3, 4**

And here is where I get stuck. I'm thinking maybe something like:

6 $Az \rightarrow Rzz \vdash Az \rightarrow Rzz$ **auxiliary assumption**
7 $\Sigma, Az \rightarrow Rzz \vdash \neg Az$ **MP, 5, 6** 
8 $\vdash \neg Az \rightarrow (\neg Rzz \rightarrow \neg Az)$ **Axiom schema a**
9 $\Sigma, Az \rightarrow Rzz \vdash \neg Rzz \rightarrow \neg Az$ **MP, 7, 8**

But then I would be stuck with the auxiliary assumption $Az \rightarrow Rzz$, which I still have to use according to the deduction theorem.

I'm looking for some better suggestions!

> EDIT -- THE FULL DEDUCTION

$\Sigma = \{\forall x \forall y ((Ax \rightarrow Rxy) \rightarrow \neg Ay)\}$

1 $\Sigma \vdash \forall x \forall y ((Ax \rightarrow Rxy) \rightarrow \neg Ay)$ **assumption** 
2 $\vdash \forall x \forall y ((Ax \rightarrow Rxy) \rightarrow \neg Ay) \rightarrow \forall y ((Az \rightarrow Rzy) \rightarrow \neg Ay)$ **Axiom schema 3**
3 $\Sigma \vdash \forall y ((Az \rightarrow Rzy) \rightarrow \neg Ay)$ **MP, 1, 2**
4 $\vdash \forall y ((Az \rightarrow Rzy) \rightarrow \neg Ay) \rightarrow (Az \rightarrow Rzz) \rightarrow \neg Az$ **Axiom schema 3**
5 $\Sigma \vdash (Az \rightarrow Rzz) \rightarrow \neg Az$ **MP, 3, 4**
6 $\vdash Rzz \rightarrow (Az \rightarrow Rzz)$ **axiom a**
7 $Rzz \vdash Rzz$ **assumption**
8 $\Sigma, Rzz \vdash Az \rightarrow Rzz$ **MP, 6, 7**
9 $\Sigma, Rzz \vdash \neg Az$ **MP, 5, 9**
10 $\Sigma \vdash Rzz \rightarrow \neg Az$ **deduction theorem, 9**
11 $\Sigma \vdash \forall x (Rxx \rightarrow \neg Ax)$ **Universal generalisation**

The hardest part is step 6 and 7. At least, I always fall for it. I just cannot fathom coming up with some "random" formula derived from axiom a, and, even worse, taking the antecedent of that axiom a derived formula and use it as an auxiliary assumption (like step 7 did)...

Comment: Basically, $((Az→Rzz)→¬Az) \rightarrow (Rzz→¬Az)$ is a *tautology*; thus, using it in step 6, you can "detach" $(Rzz→¬Az)$ and conclude with **Gen Th**. The question is : what kind of propositional theorems are you allowed to use ? If none, we have to prove it "from scratch" ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The propositional theorems you can use are the ones at the top in my post, labeled a through c. Though I don't see any that will fit $((Az \rightarrow Rzz) \rightarrow \neg Az) \rightarrow (Rzz \rightarrow \neg Az)$, so, as you put it, it has to be recreated from scratch.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was reading through it, as we speak (or type). By the way, do you assume (3) from (2)? What I always found strange, is that this axioma a can be used with any formula; apparently even formulas that do not exist in the set of given formulas of a problem... Not that it happens in this case, but still

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA another thing: everything hinges on $((Az \rightarrow Rzz) \rightarrow \neg Az) \rightarrow (Rzz \rightarrow \neg Az)$ that you came up with. That was awesome to come up with that, I don't know how I would've seen this.

Comment: Regarding the "strange" axiom-a, try to "interpret" it, remembering the truth-functional property of $\rightarrow$. If $\psi$ is *true*, then a *conditional* whatever of the "form" $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ will be *true* also, because $p \rightarrow q$ is $T$ when $q$ is $T$, independently of the truth-value of $p$. This is the "magic" behind the fact that $ψ→(φ→ψ)$ is a *tautology*, and thus we can use it as axiom.

Comment: Regarding the question "how I would've seen this ?" it is called *heuristic*: I need $Rzz→¬Az$ in order to conclude the proof, thus ... I've to "manufacture" it. To do this, first I've checked with truth-table the formula $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$; being a *tautology*, I'm sure that $\alpha \vDash \beta$. Your axiom system is *complete* for propositional calculus; thus I'm sure I can prove it. So, we have to prove it...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I've edited my post, and taken into it your sub-deduction. About your comment above here (with the complete and everything)... I understood some of those words ;-) I still got a long, long way to go... What is $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ exactly?

Comment: It is only a way of abbreviating the (to be verified) tautology : $((Az→Rzz)→¬Az)→(Rzz→¬Az)$.

Comment: If I remember well, you have only some *Lecture notes*; if you can, try to supplement them with : Derek Goldrei, [Propositional and Predicate Calculus A Model of Argument](http://www.amazon.com/Propositional-Predicate-Calculus-Model-Argument/dp/1852339217/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1401367455&sr=1-1&keywords=Derek+Goldrei+Propositional+and+Predicate+Calculus+A+Model+of+Argument) (2005). For *prop logic*, it uses the same axiom-set.

Comment: Regarding your edit : it's fine ! Regarding : "a 'random formula derived from axiom-a", we have already discussed it; step-6 is an "instance" of *axiom schema* a). Starting form an *axiom schema*, you can "manufacture" every formula you want ... **provided that** you substitute the "schematic" letters : $\varphi, \psi$, etc. in a consistent manner; i.e., in ax-a we replace **every** occurrence of $\varphi$ with an occurrence of (e.g.) $Rzz$.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Finding (((Az→Rzz)→¬Az)→(Rzz→¬Az)) doesn't take many steps.  Suppose we have 1 ((p→q)→((q→r)→(p→r))) and 2 (p→(q→p)) as our axioms. Suppose our only rule of inference is condensed detachment, and we count steps by applications of that rule. Then, there exist 4 theorems one step away from the axioms. (((p→q)→r)→(q→r)) is one of them.  The original axiom set for the implicational calculus of propositions given by Tarski and Bernays was { 1, 2, (((p→q)→p)→p) }.  1 and 2 also appear in Wajsberg's 4 axiom basis for 3-valued logic, and in a common 4 axiom basis for Lukasiewicz infinite-valued logic.

Comment: Regarding step 6 and 7, a deduction theorem usually says "if {$\gamma$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$, then $\gamma$ $\vdash$ ($\alpha$ $\rightarrow$ $\beta$)".  Now what is the converse here?  It's "if $\gamma$ $\vdash$ ($\alpha$ $\rightarrow$ $\beta$), then {$\gamma$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$".  The converse here comes as important, because you have that *anytime* you have detachment as a rule of inference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need :

> $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \lnot \varphi \vdash (\psi \rightarrow \lnot \varphi)$.

*Proof :*

*(1)* $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \lnot \varphi$ --- assumed

*(2)* $\psi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \psi)$ --- Ax.a

*(3)* $\psi$ --- assumed

*(4)* $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ --- from (2) and (3) by *modus ponens*

*(5)* $\lnot \varphi$ --- from (1) and (4) by *modus ponens*

*(6)* $\psi \rightarrow \lnot \varphi$ --- from (3) and (5) by *Deduction Theorem*.

Now you can restart from your :

> 5 $Σ \vdash (Az→Rzz)→¬Az$

to derive :

> 6 $Σ \vdash (Rzz→¬Az)$.

Comment: More generally, instead of deriving ((φ→ψ)→¬φ)⊢(ψ→¬φ) one could derive ((φ→ψ)→$\chi$)⊢(ψ→$\chi$).  There exists a few three axiom bases for propositional calculus with (((φ→ψ)→$\chi$)→(ψ→$\chi$)).